# Merge tags [google-search-api], [google-custom-search], and [google-cse]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I propose that the tags for **Google Custom Search** service be merged.

Google has a service called Google "Custom Search Engine" (CSE):
https://www.google.com/cse/
https://www.google.ca/cse/docs/

There is an API for "custom search":
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

CSE can also be used by via the Google 'control panel' and an HTML search widget.

There is a related Enterprise service called "Google Site Search":
https://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products/gss.html

In the developer docs, **Google refers to CSE and SS as 'editions' of "Google Custom Search"**.

Google has a couple of other, unrelated, search services that are offered as app engine API's (though it wouldn't surprise if Google decided to generalize them into cloud platform API's):
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/apis
The distinction is that CSE is Google Search - it theoretically uses the same search technology and content as the Google Search.   The GAE search API's, on the other hand, operate on user provided data.  For clarity they could be referred to as 'Prospective Search' and 'Datastore Search'.

---

The tags in question are:

- [google-custom-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-custom-search) with 343 questions, 11 followers.
- [google-cse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cse) with 166 questions, and 9 followers.
- [google-search-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-search-api) with 260 questions and 6 followers.

It appears to me that there is much confusion about which tags to use for questions about custom search.  Many questions use multiple redundant tags, but even more just use the generic [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/search) tag (which has 16.6K questions).

The [google-search-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-search-api) tag has a significant number of questions about the GAE search API's, though its info tab explicitly says it is for CSE.  So CSE has 3 tags, and the GAE Search API's don't really have their own tag.  If they do get their own tags I would suggest [google-prospective-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-prospective-search) and [google-datastore-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-datastore-search).  (Prospective search is brand new (still labelled experimental) so it probably has very few questions.)

Though I quite dislike all of the long tag names for Google products, I think the best one in this case is [google-custom-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-custom-search).  Note that the GAE search API's don't use the word 'custom' so that word is the key to distinguishing these products.

I haven't merged tags before and I doubt I have the points so I would need someone else to do it.  Also, I wonder whether there is a normal procedure for handling a tag such as [google-search-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-search-api) which has a significant number of mis-tagged questions.   I would suggest that the ones that also have [google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine), or [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api)   (28 and 24, respectively) get the new tag [google-datastore-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-datastore-search) and the rest get [google-custom-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-custom-search),

Comment: Also, [google-custom-search] is sponsored, and it's not nice to make them lose out on questions in their sponsored tag.