# Merge-request for [google-cloud-datastore], [gae-datastore], [google-datastore]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request, synonym-request

I think the title is pretty self-explanatory.

We currently have [google-cloud-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-datastore),[gae-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gae-datastore), and [google-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-datastore) that ALL point to the "Google App Engine datastore" and all the questions seem to have to do with it.

These should all be merged into [google-cloud-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-datastore) which is the official product name.

Comment: This appears to be a [common problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250192/merge-tags-google-search-api-google-custom-search-and-google-cse) with Google tags.

Comment: it's not the only request like that :P

Comment: If they are merged, please use `google-cloud-datastore` as the canonical name, per [this page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview).

Comment: How do we bump this? Everything really should be in `google-cloud-datastore` and while I'm slowly manually retagging from the fringe-most tags datastore and google-datastore, it's too much for me to do alone.

Comment: @Dan McGrath I'd be happy to help in that regards (the retagging itself). AFAIK, editing this question will bump it to the top of active questions.... now to get more traction on the request, I am not sure, to be honest.

Comment: I'd suggest using a custom flag with an explanation to get moderator attention - only moderators can perform tag merges, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work

Comment: Done. Also noting here that I've already manually retagged all of [google-datastore] a few months ago since it only had a few hundred questions.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for manually cleaning up [google-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-datastore).

There was already a synonym request (with two votes) from [google-cloud-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-datastore) pointing to [gae-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gae-datastore) (so the wrong direction). I swapped the direction on that request, approved it, and then merged the tags. You now have 5.4k questions tagged [google-cloud-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-datastore) *only*.

Both old names map to the official name as synonyms.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!